Wanning: is getting displayed while launching Chrome browser using selenium
Getting below warning while launching the browser
WARNING: Unable to find CDP implementation matching 129
11, 2024 10:35:48 AM org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver lambda$new$5
WARNING: Unable to find version of CDP to use for 129.0.6668.101. You may need to
include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to
org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.11.0 where the version ("v86")
matches the version of the chromium-based browser you're using and the version number
of the artifact is the same as Selenium's.
POM Dependency for selenium as below :
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

Chrome Version : Version 129.0.6668.101 (Official Build) (64-bit)


Getting this same error on Selenium 4.25.0
